# Dell Inspiron N5010 GPU not showing any display

Tags: graphics-card, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron N5010. When I turn on my laptop there is no display and 8 beeps, but it boots fine, and sometimes it also shows the display and everything works fine.

So, it works on very rare occasions. Someone suggested that my GPU is not working properly. I just want to enquire whether connecting an external monitor would solve my problem?

Comment: Connecting an external monitor will help you determine whether the issue is with your graphics card or with your laptop's screen, so if you have one, try it.

Answer (score -2):

No, external monitor works only if the GPU sends signal. So, I would recommend you to try reflowing your GPU.